# How to i place text under images that i have aligned to the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have the following lines of HTML and CSS to align 3 images to the centre of the page.
HTML:

```
<div class="row2">
  <div align="center;" class="icon">
    <img src="image/character.png" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="icon">
    <img src="image/online.png" />
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="icon">
    <img src="image/leaderboard.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

I assumed if i added text under the images it would align itself under the image, however it appears beside the image. how would i get the text to show up underneath?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the text inside a `<div>`, which is a block element and will wrap below the image.

```css
.row2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px;
}

.icon__text {
    color: dodgerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row2">
  <div align="center;" class="icon">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    <div class="icon__text">Text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="icon">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    <div class="icon__text">Text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div align="center;" class="icon">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    <div class="icon__text">Text 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works with a short text, however, if I have a paragraph under the image the text will go on in one long line. how would I get it to take multiple lines?

Comment: Set a max-width of the `icon__text` class to the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: left;` from `.icon` – it contradicts the centering anyway.

Or, if you inist on that for some reason, add `clear: both` to the tag into which your text is wrapped (probably a `<p>` tag, but you didn't describe that). This will put the text *under*  any floated element above it.